# Fatal error LNK1181 when trying to npm install web3

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, web3js

I am trying to install the web3 node package with npm install. I am aware of the fact that I first need to install Windows build tools since I am running windows:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

This command goes through fine but when I run the command to install web3 I get the following error:

```
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall [project path]\node_modules\scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js
> scrypt@6.0.3 install [project path]\node_modules\scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild
[project path]\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
[project path]\node_modules\scrypt\build\..\scrypt\win\include\config.h
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  Copying scrypt/win/include/config.h to scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/config.h
  The system cannot find the file specified.
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '[user path]\.node-gyp\9.8.0\x64\node.lib' [[project path]\node_modules\scrypt\build\copied_files.vcxproj]
  memlimit.c
  keyderivation.c
  pickparams.c
  hash.c
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  scrypt_wrapper.vcxproj -> [project path]\node_modules\scrypt\build\Release\\scrypt_wrapper.lib
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd [project path]\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v9.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     [user path]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-16T15_29_59_737Z-debug.log
```

After some additional research about why this happens I found out that the error pops up when the install process tries to install scrypt (?).
What is the problem? I have also added the environment variables for python that are required after the Windows build tools setup.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, use the path, with no spaces, or quotation marks in the path of the project properties.

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean that the project path should be without spaces, I have tried that and it does not work.

Comment: Fine first try to clear your npm cache "npm cache verify" (if you are using npm v5+ ) or "npm cache clean" for older version. after try to make a global install with admin privilege with this command "npm install --global --production windows-build-tools (Administrator privilege)"

Comment: Sadly, it still does not work, I have tried that option a few times already. May I add that I can install older versions of web3 but the newest versions are giving me this error. I am installing with the command: "npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.26"

Answer (score 0):

Ouch so sorry 'cause i can't see what's happening and why it's not working...

I've tryed and it's worked for me with this method :

1. npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
2. npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.26

And web 3 V 1.0 is correctly installed.

If someone else can help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Running as root or Administrator can fix the problem.
I had the same error. I followed Azerus's advice and created new path with only Latin letters and no spaces (actually I just created new user and logged in). But it still did not work but the error number was different. And then I got the idea to run cmd as Administrator and... it's done.

Comment: Simply running something with higher privileges can be the right solution sometimes. But it's also dangerous. So it's generally discouraged unless you know what you're doing.